# With within with in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, parameters, common-table-expression

So im trying find out the first possible termination date for apartments. It depends on a lot of things and is not so simple as it seems.

It's has like 5 scenarios and some of them depends on each other.

I was thinking i make like 5 with as for each scenario and each of them returns a date if there is one.

```
With S1 as (select date from d where contract_id = 1 
),
     S2 as (select date from e where contract_id = 1 
),
     S3 as (select date from f where contract_id = 1
),
     S4 as (with **exit_infos** as (
                                 select earliest_exit_date from g
                                 where g.id = 1
                               )
     select min(earliest_exit_date) from **exit_infos**
     where **S1.date** <= earliest_exit_date
),
     S5 as (with **months** as (
                                 select key,months from x
                                 where months > 0
                               ),
            **d_infos** as (
                                 select date_d,date_until,rental_start,amount_months from y
                                 inner join months on months.key = y.key
                                 where y.id = 1
                               ),
           **possible_date** as (
                                 select date_d
                                 from d_infos
                                 cross join lateral generate_series (case
                                                    when date_d is not null then date_d
                                                    when date_until is not null then date_until
                                                    else rental_start -1 
                                                    end, '2099-12-31'::date,amount_months)datum   

                                 
                               )
     select min(date_d)
     from possible_date
     where date_d >=s1.date
)
```

It's not possible to make new with within a with or? How can i solve this problem? I also need to be able to call value within the with from above sometimes.
Any good suggestion on how to solve this? In s4 i compare the s1.date, in s5 im using the above withs and so on.

```
select case 
when select date_s3 from s3 is not null then date_s3
when select date_s2 from s2 is not null then date_s2
when select date_s4 from s4 is not null then date_s4
when select date_s5 from s5 is not null then date_s5
else date_s1
end
```

With this case above i will get the correct date as answer in the end.

Comment: You can’t have nested `with`, but you should be able to refactor smaller reusable CTEs.

Comment: Does cte exist in Postgres? I thought with is postgres cte

Comment: CTE is the term used to describe the thing being defined using `with` - all RDBMS’s